# Split an xml file using split record processor in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

all I am new to nifi. I want to split a large xml file into multiple chunks using the split record processor.I am unable to split the records I am my original file as the output not a multiple chunks.Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I would like to know if I can split the nested loop xml file using the split record

Answer (score 0):

To use `SplitRecord`, you're going to need to create an Avro schema that defines your record. If you have that, you should be able to use the [XMLReader](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.12.0/org.apache.nifi.xml.XMLReader/index.html) to turn it into a record set.